# Is it true that drinking water before bed causes dreams to be more vivid?

Tags: sleep, dreams, feeding

[Pavan Teja says on Psychtronics](http://www.psychtronics.com/2013/11/interesting-ways-to-lucid-dream.html):

> Drink a lot of water. The more water you drink before bed, the more vivid your dreams.

Is this true? Is this because I'm more alert not to, you know, and therefore sleep less deep and therefore experience more dreams?

Comment: To my experience – and as witnessed by Winsor McCay's *Dream of the Rarebit Fiend* – *eating* before bedtime will cause your dreams to be more vivid, because, I suspect, your digestive activity keeps your sleep more shallow. I learned to not eat less than four hours before bedtime for deep and restful sleep. Drinking lots will cause me to wake up and need to go to the toilet, so I don't quite believe the "the more you ...", but of course anything that will disturb your sleep but not quite wake you will induce vivid dreams, because vivid dreams happen in the shallow sleep phases.

Comment: "We considered and rejected the use of water as a control because it would be more rapidly absorbed, leading to a brisk diuresis, rapid bladder filling, and **positive disturbance of sleep**." http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1788018/pdf/brmedj02204-0027.pdf (emphasis mine) That's all I found.

Comment: @what after reading parts of the article, I think that **positive** means that it was good for them to wake up before worse things happened. But thanks for your effort...

Comment: For any dream, all your conscious guards should be down. Unless they are down you cannot dream. If you drink lot of water before sleeping, you will be alert enough not to wet the bed. Means brains knows that body should not do this so it will be consciously guarding against this event. And if conscious is guarding then unconscious will be happy to stay away, means no dream.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more suitable for Skeptics.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at Skeptics.SE

Comment: Too old to migrate ...